# Catalog of undergraduate's misconceptions / problems while proving

Tags: undergraduate-education, reference-request, proofs, students-mistakes, undergraduate-research

Selden & Selden (2011) listed 41 difficulties their students had in an experimental proving course into 9 categories. Unfortunately I haven't found similar work. Thus, my question is:

> Is there a (more detailed) catalog of the misconceptions, typical errors or problems undergraduates have / make while proving?

**References:**

- Selden, Annie, and John Selden. "Mathematical and non-mathematical university students’ proving difficulties." *Proceedings of the 33rd annual conference of the North American chapter of the international group for the psychology of mathematics education. Reno, NV.* 2011. Retrieved from http://ejournal.narotama.ac.id/files/Mathematical%20and%20non-mathematical%20university%20students'%20proving%20difficulties.pdf

Comment: 41 difficulties in 9 categories isn't detailed enough? The link has some references. Perhaps you could start there for a pathway to related literature.

Comment: Maybe the book mentioend in this answer is of interest http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/11332/ I do not know the book at all. I just recalled that answer, and though, maybe it's relevant.

Comment: Across the entire undergraduate curriculum? Or for a particular topic? In the latter case, you might check something like: Ko, Yi-Yin, and Eric Knuth. "Undergraduate mathematics majors’ writing performance producing proofs and counterexamples about continuous functions." *The Journal of Mathematical Behavior* 28.1 (2009): 68-77. [**Link**](http://www.gram.edu/sacs/qep/chapter%204/4_23KoUndergradMath.pdf) (no pay wall).

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: Your linked article really helped me! (It's okay that it focus on a particular topic). Can you add an answer with your reference? So I can upvote it...

Comment: @StephanKulla  Any list of "misconceptions, typical errors or problems" would seem to call for a cookbook. On the other hand, watching someone struggling with a mathematical text which they are "spoozed to get" goes a long way towards our understanding of the difficulties students have in understanding _us_. And that says a lot about _us_ and the stuff _we_ say and write.